# How to fetch content in livecode

Tags: livecode

I want to catch content between two $ symbols. 
Eg: - This is $ only$ an example $so$ respond $quickly$. 
Here I want to store text between dollars (only, so and quickly) into an array. 
In using this code for catching. But it catches (only, an example, so, respond, quickly). I need "only", "so" and "quickly".

```
replace "\$" with "\XXdollarXX" in field "MytextField"
                    put the text of field "MytextField" into ss


 repeat with i = 0 to the number of chars in ss
           if char i of ss contains "$" then 
               repeat with x = i+1 to the number of chars in ss 
                   if char x of ss contains "$" then 
                      --answer x
                      put x into Lpos
                      put char i to Lpos of ss into jar
                      answer jar
                      put Lpos into i

                   end if
               end repeat 
         end if
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you examine your code while stepping through, you will see this has to work that way. The "offset" function, though, can be used in a loop, and contains a parameter "chars to skip". By continuously updating that parameter, and considering that only every other instance is pertinent, you can collect the text between the pairs of "$" as:

- between instance 1 and 2
- between instance 3 and 4
  etc.

Make a button and a field. Put some text into the field sprinkled with "$" for testing. In the button script:

```
on mouseUp
   put 0 into charsToSkip
   repeat until charsToskip > the length of fld 1
      if the optionKey is down then exit to top --YOU WILL NEED THIS RIGHT NOW...
      get offset("$",fld 1,charsToSkip)
      add it to charsToSkip
      put charsToSkip & return after accum
   end repeat
end mouseUp
```

I leave it to you to add the ability to exit this loop properly. Step through the handler and you will see the value in accum building in the way I mentioned.

Craig Newman